# What to use Map , Reduce and filter in js to convert fahrenheit to celcius

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I have an array of temperatures and i have to convert them to degree celcius , i was told i need to use map/reduce in javascript . I have looked through the documentation but i cant seem to figure out how to do it.
Here is my array :

```
var fahrenheit = [0, 32, 45, 50, 75, 80, 99, 120];
```

Comment: What documentation? There is [*ECMA-262*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html), which can be a little difficult but worth reading first. There is also the MDN [*JavaScript wiki*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript), which is a public wiki of very useful advice, though it's not an authority so it's not always technically correct, but it's still very good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
  var celcius = fahrenheit.map(function(elem) {
        return Math.round((elem - 32) * 5 / 9);
    });
```

or in ES6

```
fahrenheit.map(elem => Math.round((elem - 32) * 5 / 9));
```

and you get

```
celcius //  [-18, 0, 7, 10, 24, 27, 37, 49]
```

Comment: It is more helpful if you explain how your code works rather than providing a code–only answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in this way,

```
var fahrenheit = [0, 32, 45, 50, 75, 80, 99, 120];
var celcius = fahrenheit.map(v => ((v - 32) * (5/9)).toFixed(1));
//If you do not want the decimal points then write,
//   fahrenheit.map(v => ((v - 32) * (5/9)) | 0);

console.log(celcius); //["-17.8", "0.0", "7.2", "10.0", "23.9", "26.7", "37.2", "48.9"]
```

Formula to convert F to C is,

> C = ((F - 32) * (5 / 9))

Answer (score 0):

I guess this shall do it

```
var fahrenheit = [0, 32, 45, 50, 75, 80, 99, 120],
       celcius = fahrenheit.map(f => (f-32)/1.8);
```